# Spark remote access and free

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, data-science

I was wondering if there is any (free) Spark development environment that one can connect to and code with Python or any other language.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Databricks offers a community edition of their product which allows you to practice for free.

https://community.cloud.databricks.com/login.html